# Am I incorrectly importing my module?

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance, python-import

I've been working my way through [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex45.html), and am currently in the section where you have to code your own text-based game. I took the code from the game provided by the author and "abstracted" it until I got a sort of template I could import into the file for my own game. I want to use the classes and methods from the template module and simply provide the details that are specific to my game. This way, I don't have to rewrite everything that's in the template. The template I'm using looks like this:

```
""" This module provides some classes for constructing an interactive,
text-based game. You should ideally subclass what's provided here, and
override methods or provide new methods as you see fit.
"""
from sys import exit
from random import randint

# TODO: keep Scene class and Map class here, move everything else outside and just import (?)
# TODO: move dialogs to text files (?)
# TODO: remove 'random' import, 'sys' probably needs to stay

class Scene(object):
    """ A basic class describing a scene in your game. You should subclass this and implement your own version of enter(). """
    def enter(self):
        """ Play out the scene and return a string key referring to the next scene."""
        print "This scene is not yet configured. Subclass it and implement enter()."
        exit(1)

class Engine(object):
    """ The main engine that runs the actual game. This is where scenes are
    stepped through. You could add a system to change the starting point of
    your game depending on a save state, etc.
    """

    # initialize the engine with a map of scenes
    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        """ Initialize the engine with a map of all scenes in your game. """
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        """ Start the game with the map set at the opening scene.
        Also grab the final scene of your game. Continue through the game
        as long as you aren't at the final scene. Then, make sure you
        actually play the final scene.
        """
        # current_scene is the results of scene_map's opening_scene()
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()

        # last_scene is grabbing the next scene, with param of 'finished'
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('scene')

        # while you're not on the final scene/room
        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

        # be sure to print out the last scene
        current_scene.enter()


# TODO: abstract this class
class Map(object):
    """ Essentially holds all the scenes for your game and provides methods for grabbing the opening scene and next scene.
    Subclass this and provide your own scenes.
    """
    #scenes = {"scene": Scene()}

    def __init__(self, start_scene, scenes={"scene": Scene()}):
        # set the dictionary of scenes
        self.scenes = scenes
        """ Initialize the map with whatever your starting scene is. """
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        """ Get the value of scene_name and return it. """
        val = self.scenes.get(scene_name)
        return val

    def opening_scene(self):
        """ Return the scene your game will start with. """
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

a_map = Map('scene')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

and my own game file looks like this:

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint
from game_template import *

scenes = {
        "RudeWakeUp": RudeWakeUp(),
        "Fridge": Fridge(),
        "PlugFix": PlugFix(),
        "PlumbingFix": PlumbingFix(),
        "FridgeRelocation": FridgeRelocation(),
        "Final": Final(),
        "Fail": Fail()
        }
class Fail(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print "Well, it looks like the fridge is staying right where it is."
        exit(1)

class RudeWakeUp(Scene):
    pass

class Fridge(Scene):
    pass

class PlugFix(Scene):
    pass

class PlumbingFix(Scene):
    pass

class FridgeRelocation(Scene):
    pass

class Final(Scene):
    pass

# TEST AREA
game_map = Map('Fail', scenes)
game = Engine(game_map)
game.play()
```

I'm currently only testing `Fail()`. The problem is that when I execute my game file, I get the output from the Scene() base class in the template instead of from `Fail()`. Is this because I'm importing incorrectly, inheriting incorrectly, or something else? I've done programming in python before, but it's been a while since I've made anything significant with it and I may have forgotten some things about how classes work. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long ago, you may have learned that python is a declarative language, and code is executed line-by-line.

```
class Fail(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print "Well, it looks like the fridge is staying right where it is."
        exit(1)
scenes = {
    "RudeWakeUp": RudeWakeUp(),
    "Fridge": Fridge(),
    "PlugFix": PlugFix(),
    "PlumbingFix": PlumbingFix(),
    "FridgeRelocation": FridgeRelocation(),
    "Final": Final(),
    "Fail": Fail()
    }
```

Simply changing the order so that you declare `Fail` before you assign that class should fix the issue. In fact, you can set up `scenes` after all the other classes are declared as well.

Comment: I think I don't understand what's meant by "declare `Fail()` before you assign that class". I tried moving the class definition for `Fail()` to the bottom of the rest of my scene classes, then moved the scenes dictionary underneath all that, but I'm still getting the output from the `Scene()` base class.

Comment: Basically you need to set up the `scenes` definition *after* all your class definitions. And the **template** code is loaded before **your game** code. I put all of this in a [repl.it](https://repl.it/CbHD), and only moved `scenes` definition. The rest of the code seems to work just fine.

Comment: The template code looks like it's together with my class definitions and everything else in the same file. Is there to keep the template in it's own file and import it to use it this way, or does everything have to be in the same file?

Comment: If your `game_template` is properly packaged, I don't see how there would be any issues when you do `from game_template import *`. You would see problems when you try to execute template code without any of yours. So to test, you can replace your file with just the **import** statement and the template statements `a_map = Map('scene')` and below, then see if you get the right output of *"This scene is not yet configured. Subclass it and implement enter()."* Ideally, your code should *not* be in the same file as the template code.

Comment: I think there's a miscommunication here. The output I want isn't _"This scene is not yet configured. Subclass it and implement enter()."_, that comes from `Scene()` in the template. I'm trying to get the output from `Fail()`, which subclasses `Scene()`. The problem is that I keep getting output from `Scene()`, which suggests that my own classes aren't being implemented.

Comment: Oh I understand that; I meant the last comment as a way to test if your imports and packaging is working appropriately, to simplify any issues. The end result if everything is right should be *"Well, it looks like the fridge is staying right where it is."* once *your* code is in place.

Comment: I made another file with just the imports and a test similar to what's at the bottom of my template file. Commenting out the test in the template file let things work the way they should in the import test (I guess I was just running the test in the template instead of running the code in my game file). I've got another problem now: when running my game file, I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`. [This would be line 16](https://repl.it/CbhP/1). I know `scene_name` is a string, but `scenes` is supposed to be a dict, so I don't see why `get()` doesn't work.

Comment: Please disregard the above comment, I just realized my mistake. I was passing arguments in the wrong order to `Map()` inside my game file, meaning I was trying to pass a string when I shouldn't have been. Thank you for your help and patience with all this!